# Passing struct with 2d array to thread function and getting value of it's index

Tags: c, arrays, linux, pthreads, 2d

I am trying to pass struct to thread. Unfortunatelty when it happens i can no longer use p[i][j]. I am getting error: `subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector`

```
    typedef struct MY_M {
      int *p1;
      int *p2;

    } MY_M;



     int *M1[r];

         for (i=0; i<r; i++){
             M1[i] = (int *)malloc(c * sizeof(int));}

    pthread_t thread1;
    struct MY_M *p = malloc(sizeof(struct MY_M));
    p-> p1 = *M1;
    p-> p1 = *M2;
   int ret = pthread_create(&thread1,NULL,thread,(void*) p);



thread here:

    void* thread(void* parameter )
    {

       MY_M **p = (MY_M*)parameter;
       p->p1[0][0] = 5;


    }
```

When i comment p[0][0] the program is working fine. Why it is not working? I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: If you want to ask a new question, ask a new question rather than modifying your old one.  First you asked about passing an array of pointers, now it's a single struct... answers for one won't make sense for the other.

Comment: For your edited version, though, `p` should be `MY_M *` and your struct members are the wrong types for 2D arrays or arrays of pointers.

Comment: `p-> p1 = *M2;`: What is `M2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell exactly what you are trying to accomplish here, but I can see a number of errors.

In the first place, you assign two values to `p->p1`. I assume this is probably a mistake and you meant to assign one value to `p->p1` and another to `p->p2`. (And where did `M2` come from?)

Second, `int *M1[r];` will allocate `r` pointers to int *on the stack*, which means the array containing the buffers will become invalidated shortly after the function returns.

You are also dereferencing `M1` during assignment, which means you are only pointing to the first buffer that you allocated. Again, I can't tell exactly what you are trying to do with that, so I don't know what to recommend.

`p1` is also type `int*`, which means it contains the address of an `int`, so it can only be dereferenced once and will resolve to `int`. If you want to dereference it twice (`p->p1[x][y]`) it should be type `int**` or pointer to some other dereference-able type.

Also, you cast `parameter` to `MY_M*`, but then assign it to a variable of type `MY_M**`. That is not correct (in fact, isn't that giving you a compiler error?)

As far as I can tell, you are simply trying to allocate some structure that your thread will later have access to. If that is the case, the code would be something like this:

```
typedef struct MY_M {
    int* p1;
    int* p2;
} MY_M;

MY_M* p = (MY_M*)malloc( sizeof(MY_M) );

p->p1 = (int*)malloc( c * sizeof(int) );
p->p2 = (int*)malloc( c * sizeof(int) );

pthread_t thread1;

int ret = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, thread, (void*)p);
```

thread here:

```
void* thread(void* parameter)
{
   MY_M *p = (MY_M*)parameter;
   p->p1[0] = 5;
}
```

Overall, it seems that you don't fully understand pointers properly. I can try to give a brief rundown, but do consult other guides and references to fully understand the concept.

First: a pointer is an address. So `int* a = &b;` means that `a` of type `int*` will contain `b`'s address, and therefore it *points* to `b`. If you *dereference* a pointer, that means you take the address value that it holds and follow the address to its original source. So `*a` dereferences a, resolving to the value stored in `b`.

Array index syntax is equivalent to offset + dereferencing, so when you say `p->p1[0][0]`, that is really equivalent to `*((*(p->p1+0))+0)`, which dereferences the variable twice.

You can't dereference something that isn't a pointer (i.e., doesn't contain an address). That's why your `int*` can't be dereferenced twice. After dereferencing it once, it is now an `int`, which does not contain an address and cannot be dereferenced.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

What you're actually using is an array of pointers (to arrays), rather than a proper 2D array -- though that isn't really a problem here.  As for why it isn't working, you simply have the wrong type for `p` in your thread function -- it should be `int **` rather than `int *`.